# how can we display html form values as many times as the user insert them by pressing submit button each time?

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <form  action="#"></form>
         <label for="First-name">First name: </label>
         <input type="text" id="First-name" placeholder="Please insert fiid."><br>
        <label for="Second-name">Second name:   </label>
        <input type="text"  id="Second-name"   placeholder="Please insert second name"> <br>
        <label for="Passenger-weight">Passengers weight:   </label>
        <input type="number" class="weight" id ="Passenger-weight"  placeholder="Please enter passengers weight"><br>
        <label for="cargo-weight">cargo weight:   </label>
        <input type="number"  class="weight" id ="cargo-weight" placeholder="Please enter cargo weight"><br>
       <input type="submit" id ="submit" ><br> 
      </form>
      <p id="sum"></p>
      <div id="sumoftotal"></div>
      
      
<body>
 <script language="JavaScript">
document.getElementById("submit").onclick=function (){
  let firstName = document.getElementById("First-name").value;
let lastName= document.getElementById("Second-name").value;
 let num1 = document.getElementById("Passenger-weight").value;
 let num2 = document.getElementById("cargo-weight").value;
let total =parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2); 
document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML=(`${firstName} ${lastName} ${total }`)
}
  </script> 
</body>
```

my problem can be numbered:
number 1: when I press the submit button, input values show up, BUT when I want to insert a different data, the previous one disappear. I studied about it, because whatever comes in the function scope become local we cannot apply it outside, BUT I don't know how to change it.
number 2: I want to have the sum of total weights I insert at the end of my list, I know we can do this by loop, BUT I need something simpler and more preliminary because I am a novice and it would be a big jump for the time being.
all in all, I would be happy if anyone could help me.

Comment: Instead of clicking a submit button you could listen [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the primary and most basic approach.

```js
var data = document.getElementById('data');
var weightElement = document.getElementById('total-weight');
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {

  /* Getting data */
  let firstName = document.getElementById("First-name").value;
  let lastName = document.getElementById("Second-name").value;
  let num1 = document.getElementById("Passenger-weight").value;
  let num2 = document.getElementById("cargo-weight").value;
  let total = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);

  /* Appending element */
  data.innerHTML = data.innerHTML + `First Name - ${firstName}, Last Name - ${lastName}, Weight - ${total} <br/>`;
  weightElement.innerHTML = parseInt(weightElement.innerHTML) + total;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form action="#"></form>
  <label for="First-name">First name: </label>
  <input type="text" id="First-name" placeholder="Please insert fiid."><br>
  <label for="Second-name">Second name: </label>
  <input type="text" id="Second-name" placeholder="Please insert second name"> <br>
  <label for="Passenger-weight">Passengers weight: </label>
  <input type="number" class="weight" id="Passenger-weight" placeholder="Please enter passengers weight"><br>
  <label for="cargo-weight">cargo weight: </label>
  <input type="number" class="weight" id="cargo-weight" placeholder="Please enter cargo weight"><br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit"><br>
  </form>
  <div id="data"></div>
  <div>Total weight = <span id="total-weight">0</span></div>
</body>
```

Comment: tnx, but is there any way to do this without appendchild and creat element?

Comment: @honey Updated the answer to more simplified version

Comment: I did, the thing is the only instruments I have is function with return and object with operators, I ought to solve it with a limited source. my question is why I cannot display multiple data in  lines and how to add a total sum when I cannot use loop. tnx for update but my problem is not still solved.

Comment: Oh, so you want the total sum as in the sum of all the passengers?

Comment: @honey Can you check now! If it solves your problem

Comment: @Nik Please use runnable snippets for html/js/css solutions. That way people can run the code and see your answer.

Comment: as soon as possible check !

Comment: It got way better, but you unfortunately I have a very limited source, my tutor told me that I am allowed to use w3school till the end of event section and solve this problem with that otherwis, I once solved it with loop and it worked correctly but this time he wants me to improve problem solving:

Comment: this was my best effort, others don't work.

Comment: data.innerHTML = data.innerHTML...............I DONT get this one. why did you repeat it?

Comment: It just takes the previous HTML and adds the current one to it.

Comment: wow so great, I NEVER came up with var data and var weightelement. does this problem solving come out by practice or it needs talent?

Comment: is there any way to have totals individually and then on  a whole?

Comment: look when I ADDED total variable, it show total weigh as zero:

Comment: @honey Updated the code snippet. You can check

Comment: data.innerHTML = data.innerHTML + `Passenger:  ${firstName},  ${lastName}, ${total} <br/>`;
          weightElement.innerHTML = parseInt(weightElement.innerHTML) + total;

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be 0, when you didn't input any value?

Comment: <script>
let myNumber = 2; 
let txt = "";
while (myNumber != Infinity) {
   myNumber = myNumber * myNumber;
   txt = txt + myNumber + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
</script>

Comment: I wonder if you are available and could talk to me about this code? You know, my question is not about the infinity, I wonder why we defined a txt variable and is it this way that in the specified function we use txt variable with its assignment as string as a plate to store our calculation?

Comment: all in all why do we need a variable to specify a string? does it have something to do with storing data?